# Binding ContentView to ContentPage

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, mvvm, binding

I am trying to implement a xamarin app that will have a MainPage like a container that will host the rest of my pages(as content view?).

MainPage.xaml

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
         xmlns:views="clr-namespace:TalosLib"
         mc:Ignorable="d"
         x:Class="TalosLib.MainPage">


<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout >

        <StackLayout.Resources>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="login">
                <views:LoginPage />
            </DataTemplate>
        </StackLayout.Resources>
        
        <ContentView Content="{Binding CurrentView}" ControlTemplate="{StaticResource login}"/>
    <!--<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding CurrentView}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource login}"/>-->
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

MainPageModel.cs

```
public class MainPageModel : FreshBasePageModel
{
    //private ObservableCollection<LoginPageModel> _currentView;

    //public ObservableCollection<LoginPageModel> CurrentView
    //{
    //    get { return _currentView; }
    //    set { _currentView = value; RaisePropertyChanged("CurrentView"); }
    //}

    private LoginPageModel _currentView;

    public LoginPageModel CurrentView
    {
        get { return _currentView; }
        set { _currentView = value; RaisePropertyChanged("CurrentView"); }
    }

    public override void Init(object initData)
    {
        base.Init(initData);
        //CurrentView = new ObservableCollection<LoginPageModel>();
        //CurrentView.Add(new LoginPageModel());
        CurrentView = new LoginPageModel();
        RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(CurrentView));
    }


}
```

Right now i am trying just to show the LoginPage but it doesn't appear. I managed to make it work if i used the commented parts of the code. i am using FreshMVVM. Any thoughts?

Comment: is LoginPage a ContentPage or a ContentView?

Comment: LoginPage is ContenView

Comment: @kaza.ma Here is [another discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63058029/switch-templates-in-xamarin-based-of-bound-property-not-itemtemplate/63131046#63131046) , it seems like the same problem with you. However, it not use FreshMVVM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Control templates help you define the root view like navbar or headers in all pages. I am not sure why you want to bind content property if you want to use a static resource. If you are going to change the content then we can use data templates and use a converter to convert the ViewModel to view.

If you are interested to change the content of the ContentView, then you can use data templates as follows:

```
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <views:DataTemplateToViewConverter x:Key="dataTemplateToViewConverter" />

        <DataTemplate x:Key="Login">
            <views:LoginView />
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="Demo">
            <views:DemoView />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ResourceDictionary>


     <ContentView x:Name="contentview" Content="{Binding MyTemplate, Converter={StaticResource dataTemplateToViewConverter}}" />
        <Button
            Command="{Binding Clicked1}"
            Text="1" />
        <Button
            Command="{Binding Clicked2}"
            Text="2" />
```

In your ViewModel, you can use the command interface and set the templates
on clicked commands.. don't forget to create your MyTemplate bindable property.

```
    private void Clicked2Called(object obj)
    {
        MyTemplate = "DemoView";
    }

    private void Clicked1Called(object obj)
    {
        MyTemplate = "Login";
    }
```

In your converter you can do as follows:

```
  public class DataTemplateToViewConverter : IValueConverter
  {
    public DataTemplateToViewConverter()
    {
    }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value.ToString() == "Login")
            return new LoginView();
        else
            return new DemoView();
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
  }
```

There are lots of ways to do this still better...I have used buttons to change the content, I am not sure how you wish to change the views when the menu items are selected. Hope it helps you solve your problem.

Comment: Maybe my question wasn't clear enough. LoginPage is an example. What i am trying to do is to have a MainPage with a menu and the rest of the area will be used to show all my views depending what the user selected and all the handling will be done by MainPageModel just by changing the CurrentView Property that is bound with a control in MainPage. CurrentView won't be type of LoginPageModel.

Comment: @kaza.ma please check if edited answer suits your needs.